# wp sidebar and footer (widget areas) disappeared

Tags: wordpress, widget, footer, sidebar

I am using the [Adapt theme](http://www.wpexplorer.com/adapt-free-responsive-wordpress-theme/) by wp-explorer.  Though I have done quite a few css edits, everything was working fine until recently.  Now my wp theme is missing the sidebar and footer areas. For example http://www.mipsmusic.com/media/ should have a sidebar on the right and a footer on the bottom.  In the wp-admin area the widget area is gone. (There are still widgets, but no widget areas to drag n drop the widgets into)

I have tried:

- deactivating all plugins
- checking single.php for `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` and `<?php get_footer(); ?>` and the tags are right there at the bottom of the page.
- switching to the twenty eleven theme to see if it was a theme problem.

The results were the same in each case: no sidebar, no footer, and no widget areas in the back end.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Do I need to do a fresh wp install manually?  If so, does anyone know a good tutorial for it - I don't want to lose all my edits.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I tried the wordpress debugging and in the widget area and I believe this is my problem...but what do I do to fix this?

Fatal error: Call to undefined function dynamic_sidebar()

Answer (score 0):

There is a fatal PHP error right as your sidebar begins. You can see this if you look at the source of the page (View Source):

```
</article>
<!-- /post -->


<aside id="sidebar" class="clearfix">
```

That is the very end of your document. Those are the last lines. That is where the fatal error occurs, which stops the generation of the page. Either there is an error in your theme, or in a widget. Enable [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and it should give you a hint. Edit your answer to include that information and I will try to help more. Until then, this is the best answer I've got.

Edit:

The undefined function error you posted suggests a broken WordPress install, not a problem with the widgets themselves. [`dynamic_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) is a core WordPress function. It should not ever really be 'undefined'. I would suggest re-uploading the `wp-includes` and `wp-admin` folders to your site. Sounds like you have missing or corrupt files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The debug tip was great.  Found fatal error in widget area and it has to do with undefined function in dynamic sidebar - what would I do to fix this? (full notice included in post edit above)